# How can i send a random collection whenever a GET request made in my Node.js API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently working on a typing app that has an API that will send random quotes like this one https://api.quotable.io/random i scripted an API via mongodb nodejs and express and it works well but i want to send a random collection from the database whenever user made a GET request to /random i tried mongoose-random package but it just returned an empty array how can i fix it.

```
const express = require('express')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var random = require('mongoose-random');

const router = express.Router()
const lesson = require('../models/subscriber')
// Get all subscribers
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const subscribers = await lesson.find()
    res.json(subscribers)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
lesson.findRandom().limit(10).exec(function (err, iterat) {
    console.log(iterat);
});


// Get one subscriber
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const subscriber = new lesson({
    content: req.body.content,
    subject: req.body.subject
  })

  try {
    const newSubscriber = await subscriber.save()
    res.status(201).json(newSubscriber)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})

async function getSubscriber(req, res, next) {
  try {
    subscriber = await lesson.findById(req.params.id)
    if (subscriber == null) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cant find subscriber'})
    }
  } catch(err){
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }

  res.subscriber = subscriber
  next()
}
// Update one subscriber
router.patch('/:id', getSubscriber, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.name != null) {
    res.subscriber.content = req.body.content
  }

  if (req.body.subject != null) {
    res.subscriber.subject = req.body.subject
  }
  try {
    const updatedSubscriber = await res.subscriber.save()
    res.json(updatedSubscriber)
  } catch {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
  }

})
router.get('/:id', getSubscriber, (req, res) => {
    res.json(res.subscriber)
})

// Delete one subscriber
router.delete('/:id', getSubscriber, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await res.subscriber.remove()
    res.json({ message: 'Deleted This Subscriber' })
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})


module.exports = router
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var random = require('mongoose-random');
const subscriberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  subject: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

subscriberSchema.plugin(random,{path:'r'});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Subscriber', subscriberSchema)

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var random = require('mongoose-random');
const subscriberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  subject: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

subscriberSchema.plugin(random,{path:'r'});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Subscriber', subscriberSchema)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you fetching a single document from the collection.

```
    const count = await Quote.estimatedDocumentCount();
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
    Quote.findOne()
      .skip(random)
      .then((quote) => {
        return res.status(200).json({
          statusCode: 200,
          quote: quote,
        });
      });
```

For your reference

https://github.com/pprathameshmore/QuoteGarden/blob/3ca9cf657e76871c4d9a8aa4a5bd20fca78ff1f8/api/controllers/quotesV2.js#L7

Comment: Now it says "documentCount is not defined"

Comment: @YusufArdaVardar Upvoting could help others.